# cakephp doesn't work url-rewriting on Ubuntu

Tags: apache, cakephp, mod-rewrite, cakephp-2.1

all. This time I try cakephp, but I have got "URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server. 1) Help me configure it 2) I don't / can't use URL rewriting". I could know this is apache and .htaccess issues such as /etc/apache2/sites-avaliable/default and each directory .htaccess.

My development environment...

- Ubuntu12.04 on vmware fusion4
- apache2.2.22
- mysql5.5
- php5.3.10
- cakephp2.1

My process is followed...

1)/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

2)enabling mod_rewrite

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 reload
```

3)editing /etc/apache2/sites-avaliable/default (AllOverride None to AllOverride All)

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

prompt: sudo service apache2 reload
```

4)editing or checking each .htaccess file
->cake root directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
   </IfModule>
```

->app root directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
   </IfModule>
```

->webroot directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

This issue is solved, thank you.

Comment: For me this did the trick.
sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo service apache2 reload

Comment: I did everything except step 1.. thanks ^^"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this problem as well. Turns out the **.htaccess** file was not getting copied alongside the cakePHP source. This is a common issue when using the cp command or not having hidden files visible in a file browser, unless you copy the top-level directory.

Doing a direct copy of the file to my project folder fixed it for me without having to mess with my apache settings.

```sh
cp ~/git/cakePHP/.htaccess ~/project/folder/
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible missconfiguration:

Check if File `http://your_domain_name/css/cake.generic.css` is rechable from your Browser. If not you will get the warning in the Default-Homepage

If you have a **`{HOME}/css`** Directory at the root level, UrlRewriting will not redirect `http://your_domain_name/css/cake.generic.css` to `{HOME}/app/webroot/css/cake.generic.css`.

Thus the css-File will not be found, causing the Message that URL-rewriting is not properly configured. (Look at File app/View/Pages/home.cpt)

**Solution:** Completly remove `{HOME}/css` Directory at root-level. Put your css-File at `{HOME}/app/webroot/css`.

Answer (score -1):

This could be a file permissions problem. Try recursively setting permissions to 777 for both the webroot and tmp directories. The tmp directory might require sudo.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/app/webroot/
sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/app/tmp/
```

Comment: You can't simply give 777 permission to webroot. That will lead to zero security