# CakePHP URL rewriting not working on Ubuntu

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, ubuntu

I can't seem to get URL rewriting to work on a Ubuntu 12.04 server with apache2 and when the default page loads (home) it's just plain text without CSS . I'm using Cake 2.3.9 and I get the following message upon a fresh install to /var/www/. So my root directory looks like

```
/var/www/app
/var/www/lib
/var/www/index.php
/var/www/.htaccess
....
```

The error I get is

> URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server. 1. Help me configure it 2. I don't / can't use URL rewriting

I tried everything in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835344/cakephp-doesnt-work-url-rewriting-on-ubuntu) but I stil get the message.

The only thing from that post I didn't do is the accepted answer, which was

> Turns out the .htaccess file was not getting copied alongside the cakePHP source.
>        This is a common issue when using the cp command or not having hidden files visible 
>        in a file browser, unless you copy the top-level directory.
>        Doing a direct copy of the file to my project folder fixed it for me without having to mess with my apache settings.

Is that user suggesting to make sure .htaccess is /var/www? I don't quite get what they're suggesting to do. I downloaded Cake locally and then used SFTP to upload it to /var/www on my ubuntu server.

Unless there is some alternate modrewrite setting, I'm almost positive it's enabled. When I type `sudo a2enmod rewrite` it says `Module rewrite already enabled`

I've also tried everything [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html) and still no luck. I'm completely stuck.

Comment: I think mod_rewrite isn't enabled in the apache service

Comment: When I type 'sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo service apache2 reload' it says 'Module rewrite already enabled'

Answer (score 0):

Yes, .htaccess will need to be in the public web root directory - /var/www in this case.
Make sure the file is readable by your web server, too.

If this doesn't work:
Make sure that the mod_rewrite module is installed and enabled. It should be on Ubuntu 12.04. 
You can check by listing the contents of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled. You should see rewrite.load listed.

If not, you can enable it as so:

```
sudo -i
cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
ln -s ../sites-available/rewrite.load rewrite.load
apache2ctl restart
```

Comment: I'm using apache2 so I did cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled. When I tried to make the link it responds with "ln: failed to create symbolic link `rewrite.load': File exists"

Comment: Yes, apache2 - will edit the answer. 
Looks like it's already there, then. Should show the simlink when doing an LS.

Comment: I tried your edited answer and it still  gives the message "ln: failed to create symbolic link `rewrite.load': File exists"

Comment: Sorry - I mean that you don't need to create the link, as the file exists - so this enabled (looks like you've the same answer from a2enmod).

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled and reinstalled my LAMP stack and it now works. I also downgraded to CakePHP 2.3.8 from 2.3.9, so maybe there was something in there too.

Regardless, it's now working!